# не отображается картинка в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Вот такую ошибку мне выдает  **couldn't recognize data in image file**

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=1200, height=1200)
filename = PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\JURAPC\\Desktop\\домашка\\Python\\art\\295005.jpg")


c.create_image(0, 0, image=filename, anchor="nw")

c.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А вы пробовали какие-нибудь другие файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат JPG не поддерживается. Необходимо установить пакет pillow:
`pip install pillow`.
Затем измените вашу программу на:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root, width=1200, height=1200)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\\Users\\JURAPC\\Desktop\\домашка\\Python\\art\\295005.jpg"))

c.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но я просто перевел картинку в png формат

Answer (score 0):

Примерный код (для gif-формата). Если формат другой, то надо использовать PIL(код ниже)

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
im = PhotoImage(file='myfile.gif')
l = Label(root, image=im)
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Вот:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x1000') #задает размер окна
canvas = Canvas(root,width=1200,height=1200)
canvas.pack()
pilImage = Image.open("example.png")
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
imagesprite = canvas.create_image(400,400,image=image)
root.mainloop()
```